Even though the bike was underneath CCTV, they weren't going to look at the footage. | Why ".....weren't going to do...."?
On TV, someone whose bike was stolen is complaining about it not being taken seriously. He says:
"When I spoke to the police even though the bike was underneath CCTV, they weren't going to look at the footage. It's unacceptable." Britain's crime wave (see:5:42-5:50)
The structure ".....were going to do something ..." is usually used for situations that were planned but couldn't take place for some reason, like "They were going to bake a cake, but they couldn't, because the electricty was out."
But the structure "... weren't going to look ...." seems to have a different function here in this sentence, which I can't be sure of. Does it mean:
1-They would not look at it (Although the man insisted on they do it, they didn't do it.)
2- They did not look at it. (They simply didn't do it, they didn't make any explanation about it, they came, filled in some forms and went away.)
Really, why might he have used the structure "....weren't going to do...." instead of "....didn't do ..."?

"BE going to do" something expresses an intention.  The police had no intention of looking at the footage.
Stated the other way around, "The police intended not to look at the footage."
P.S. When you say that a group "were not going to do" something in a reported-speech context, the original, before their words were cast to the past tense, is "We are not going to ...",  which means that they  made a decision not to do it.

It means more than the fact that the police did not look at the footage, which would be quite mild.
It means the first one:

1-They would not look at it.

There’s a sense of refusal or brushing aside the request.
The sentence would be better with the 'even though' clause shifted to the end:
When I spoke to the police, they weren't going to look at the footage even though the bike was underneath CCTV.

So, do you mean that "They did look at the footage.?"

No.  It means more than the fact that the police did not look at the footage.  I have edited my answer for clarity.

"They were not intending to look at it" - they had no plans to do so.

@KateBunting, Thanks "intend" is the main thing that differentiates "...were going to do...." from "....would do....". I now understand better. So, they didn't have the intention of looking even at the beginning when they came. Does it also mean "they were not intending and they did not look at it" or we may not know whether they looked at it or not in the end?

@Yunus, They were not intending to look at it most likely leads to the police not viewing it.  This attitude is what makes it reprehensible.  Some sort of viewing might actually happen, but even so it would more likely be due to some unplanned events.
